# Проблема с импортом модели из Maya в Unity. Слетают материалы при проигрыше анимации

Tags: unity3d

Модель в формате FBX импортирую в Unity, на ней несколько материалов разных цветов. Сама модель содержит в себе клип с анимацией, и вот тут начинается непонятные для меня траблы.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Все цвета модели слетают напрочь, то есть с самой моделью в сцене все норм, но когда начинается проигрыш анимации, она в первый же кадр становится бесцветной, как и на скриншоте в окне анимации. Помогите пожалуйста, буду очень благодарен.
  [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: В правом нижнем углу есть кнопка выбора аватара. Выбери аватар модели(когда просматриваешь анимацию), а не анимации. Думаю что анимация использует свой собственный аватар, который не содержит необходимых материалов